# Getting an error when passing the table name as parameter to a function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am new to SQL query and here I am trying to get the complete name from dbo.Customer_List table and have written this code. However when try to run am getting the following error. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Error message is:

```
Msg 1087, Level 16, State 1, Procedure getFullName, Line 11
Must declare the table variable "@tblName".
Msg 1087, Level 16, State 1, Procedure getFullName, Line 14
Must declare the table variable "@tblName".
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'Last_Name'.
```

Code is:

```
IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.getFullName', N'FN') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION getFullName
GO

Create function dbo.getFullName(@tblName varchar(30),@fstName varchar(50), @lstName varchar(50) ) returns varchar(101)
As
Begin

    Declare @rowCount int
    Declare @rowIteration int
    Declare @temp varchar(101)

        Select @rowCount = count(*) from @tblName
        Set @rowIteration = 1
  While ( @rowIteration <= @rowCount)
    Select @temp =  @fstName+' '+@lstName from @tblName where @tblName.Customer_Id = @rowIteration
    Begin

        Set @rowIteration = @rowIteration + 1
    End 
    return @temp
End

Go


Declare @tblName varchar(30),@fstName varchar(50), @lstName varchar(50)

set @tblName = convert(varchar(30),'dbo.Customer_List')
set @fstName = convert(varchar(50),'dbo.Customer_List.First_Name')
set @lstName = convert(varchar(50),'dbo.Customer_List.Last_Name')

Execute ('select dbo.getFullName('+ @tblName+','+ @fstName+','+ @lstName )
```

Comment: You cannot use variables for table or column names. And, why you just don't query "select First_Name + ' ' + Last_Name as Full_Name from dbo.Customer_List"?

Comment: Which dbms? (This doesn't look like ANSI SQL...)

Comment: I have written the code in SQL Server 2008 wherein I am passing the table's name and column's name as parameter to a function to get the Full Name of a client.

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially trying to perform dynamic sql here without performing it properly. You can't just pass in a variable as a table name, that's why you're getting your error.

You need to recreate this as a stored procedure (or at least you will in sql-server which does not like DML transactions in functions) and use the following dynamic sql:

```
Declare @sql nvarchar(100)

Set @sql = 'Set @int = (Select count(*) from ' + @tblName + ')'

execute sp_executesql @sql, N'@int int output', @int = @rowCount output
```